# Nativescript Picker with images and file upload

Tags: image, typescript, upload, widget, nativescript

I've implemented a RadDataForm Form in my Nativescript Core code but I'm trying to figure out how to implement a dropdown list (editor of type Picker) that can display a small image next to text for each option in the list, if that's not possible then to make each option a different color.

The other thing I haven't manage to figure out is how to implement an file upload option within RadDataForm.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the RadDataForm picker supports images. But you may use the custom editor option and inject plugins like [nativescript-filterable-listpicker](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-filterable-listpicker) inside which would make your job easy.

File upload works differently on native apps unlike web ones. Web apps do not have control over file system but native apps do. You may inject a button into your form and upon clicking that, use plugins like image / media picker to get the file and update your data form's source object with base64 string of the selected file. Or if you prefer multi-part upload, keep the reference of the file path and use background http plugin.